# OpenCV IplImage save/read to video

Tags: c++, opencv, video, iplimage

I'm trying to save a video to analyse later with OpenCV algorithms.
I'm using a C++ library of the camera to obtain the frames.

```
IplImage  *iplImageInput = QueryFrame(); //runs every 30 ms
std::vector <cv::Mat> splittedVector;
cv::split(cv::Mat(iplImageInput), splittedVector);  //stereo vision camera
// splittedVector buffer is used by the algorithms
```

So I would like to replace the function "QueryFrame()" with data saved before.
I have already tried some things with cv::videowriter/cv::videocapture but with no luck.

Do you have any hints to eliminate the need for the camera while testing algorithms? 
How should I implement a writer and reader to save like 150 frames?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use `cv::VideoCapture` for reading file sequences: in the documentation says "VideoCapture::VideoCapture(const string& filename) -> filename – name of the opened video file (eg. video.avi) or image sequence (eg. img_%02d.jpg, which will read samples like img_00.jpg, img_01.jpg, img_02.jpg, ...)"

Comment: do *not* use IplImages any more, the c-api is deprecated, and a pita for noobs.

Comment: to append to @KeillRandor's idea above, you could save a series of images like: `cv::imwrite(frame, cv::format("img_%03d.jpg", counter));` (you will need the leading zeros for lexical sorting on disk)